# Extraordinarily Forgoes Anthem

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, geography, cryptic-clues

> 1. Island oranges don't mix well (11)
> 2. Liquid wastes run into river (10, 4)
> 3. Cold canines found in the mountains (10)
> 4. A season before a season's past in Northern capital (10)
> 5. City at the top of the stairs is horror writer's area (5, 7)

**Where are we?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Island oranges don't mix well (11)

> DRAGONSTONE (anagram of "oranges don't")

Liquid wastes run into river (10, 4)

> BLACKWATER RUSH (BLACKWATER is a term for liquid waste, and RUSH is a synonym of "run")

Cold canines found in the mountains (10)

> FROSTFANGS ("cold" + "canines")

A season before a season's past in Northern capital (10)

> WINTERFELL (WINTER (a season), before FELL (past of "fall", another season))

City at the top of the stairs is horror writer's area (5, 7)

> KING'S LANDING (KING refers to horror writer Stephen King, and a LANDING is the area at the top of a staircase)

---

From the answers to these clues, we can clearly see you are in

> the world of Game of Thrones, since all of the answers refer to locations in that series. (And the title is also cryptic wordplay -- "forgoes anthem" is an anagram of "Game of Thrones"!)